# Grab only part of the screen with pyscreenshot

Tags: python, linux, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to crop an screenshot of my screen with pyscreenshot, I want to set specific size to grab, But I don't know how to use it correctly.

Lets say I want to get only the top left corner in my screen, so for example I use this sizes

```
# (0, 80) (0, 60)
image = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(0, 80, 0, 60))
```

But When I run my program, this error pops up:
`ValueError: bbox x2<=x1`

Comment: Well it says the second argument is smaller or equal to the first, so try `(0, 60, 10, 80)` instead maybe?

Comment: @Mandera But what if I let the user to choose his size ?

Comment: What's the problem with that?

Comment: @Mandera , what if the user set second argument smaller or equal to the first

Comment: Then you could add a check for that, where in which case you could just switch them. Even better would be if you let the user select two points, then you take the lowest values for each axis from both points as the first argument. Then take the remainding highest value for each axis as the second argument

Comment: @Mandera Can you please give me an example. I didn't fully understand you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215800/discussion-between-mandera-and-bar).